# Drawings in drawRect not being displayed correctly

Tags: cocoa-touch, drawrect

I want to implement freeform drawing in my app. First, I tried the code inside `drawLayer:inContext:` and it gave me the result I wanted.

**Drawing in CALayer:**

[image: CALayer drawing implementation]

But when I decided to implement the code inside `drawRect:`, this happened:

[image: drawing implemented in drawRect: method]

Even if I draw inside the white space, the drawing is rendered *outside* as shown above. The code I used is exactly the same. I copy-pasted it from `drawLayer:inContext:` to `drawRect:`. I didn't change a thing, so why is this happening?

**The Code:**

```
CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

CGContextSetLineCap(ctx, kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 1.0);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 1, 0, 0, 1);
CGContextBeginPath(ctx);
CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, prevPoint.x, prevPoint.y);
for (NSValue *r in drawnPoints){
    CGPoint pt = [r CGPointValue];
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, pt.x, pt.y);
}
CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using app in full screen mode where the view is centered and does not take full width of the screen.

It may be that `CALayer` has transform applied to it that translates the drawing from the left side of the screen to the center. This may not be the case with `drawRect:`. Try setting CGContext's transform matrix:

```
CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
CGFloat xOffset = CGRectGetMidX(screenFrame) - CGRectGetMidX(viewFrame);
CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, xOffset, 0.0f);
// rest of drawing code
// ...
CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what is the difference of the screen frame from the view frame?

Comment: What I did is this `CGFloat xOffset = CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) - CGRectGetMidX(contentView.frame)` where `contentView` is the white page where I want to draw. I can draw anywhere in the UIView, *except* for the `contentView` itself. It's like it is "hovering" above the view.